# How can I do model binding for an action in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On my HTML I have something like this:

```
<input id="City_Name" name="City.Name" size="15" type="text" value="" />
<input disabled="disabled" id="Location" name="Location" size="15" type="text" value="" />
```

The first field binds to the City.Name in my model. However the second field needs to bind to City.Location.

Is there a simple way that I can make this bind to the correct field in my model?

Comment: How about changing the name attribute to `City.Location`?

Comment: I made the example simple but actually there is much more to it. The second field is generated from a HTML.RenderPartial which generates many fields all without the City prefix.

Comment: This seems a case where you want to use editor templates, not partial views.

Comment: disabled fields dont get posted use a hidden field so that its value get posted

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you fixing your markup and having the field name `City.Location` instead of `Location`. Always use editor templates, they will generate proper field names for your inputs so that you don't have to worry about it. As a side note your field is marked as `disabled` which means that its value will never be sent to the server no matter how it is named.